# pass a list to be matched in where/having clause

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

MySQL table looks like

```
product_id    material
----------------------
1             A
1             B
1             C
2             A
2             B
3             A
3             B
3             C
3             D
4             A
4             B
4             D
```

I want all those **product_id**s which have material A,B,C

Hence output should be 1, 3

Using group by seem appropriate, but how to pass multiple **material** to be matched.

The number of materials to be matched can vary, i.e. 1st query maybe for material A,B,C 
*output : 1,3*
 and 2nd query might be for material A,D
*output : 3,4*

What query should I write in Hibernate in java program, and a mysql query as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Query**

```
SELECT product_id 
FROM products
WHERE material IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT material) = 3;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b73d/2)

Comment: In this instance, the combination of columns is presumably/hopefully unique, so DISTINCT *should* be unnecessary- but no harm including it I guess